# Elementwise logical comparison of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean-operations, elementwise-operations

I have two numpy arrays of the same shape. The elements in the arrays are random integers from [0,N]. I need to check which (if any) of the elements in the same position in the arrays are equal.

The output I need are the positions of the same elements.

mock code:

```
A=np.array([0,1])
B=np.array([1,0])
C=np.array([1,1])
np.any_elemenwise(A,B)
np.any_elemenwise(A,C)
np.any_elemenwise(A,A)
```

desired output:

```
[]
[1]
[0,1]
```

I can write a loop going through all of the elements one by one, but I assume that the desired output can be achieved much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT:The question changed.

You just want to evaluate `np.where(v1==v2)[0]`

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer and decided to drop the truth-value because I was thinking that I can always check len(output)==0.

Comment: no problem, I think the updated question shows a better design anyway.