# Testing if rows in a numpy array are the same as a given row or different by each element

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This is related to my earlier question: [Elementwise logical comparison of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605554/elementwise-logical-comparison-of-numpy-arrays/22605851#22605851)

I have two numpy arrays of random integers

```
A=np.random.randint(Q,size=(N,M))
B=np.random.randint(Q,size=(1,M))
```

I need to test if any of the rows in A have more than 0 and less than M common elements elementwise with B.

For example if

```
A=np.array([[2,0],[0,1],[1,2]])
B=np.array([1,0])
```

I would expect `True` since `[1,0]` and `[1,2]` share more than 0 and less than 2 elements elemenwise.

On the other hand if

```
B=np.array([2,0])
```

I would expect `False` since there are only rows which chare 2 or 0 elements elementwise

At the moment my approach is:

```
c=np.where((A[:]==B))[0]
n=np.bincount(c)
((n==0)+(n==2)).all()
```

To me this seems like a convoluted way of testing this and I was wondering if there was a more natural way that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
neq=(A==B).sum(-1)
result = any(logical_and(neq<B.size, neq>0))
```

where `neq` keeps track of how many digits each line of `A` has in common with `B`.